# How to execute stored procedure with Output parameters using FromSqlInterpolated/Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated in Dot Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I would like to execute a stored procedure with output parameter in Dot Net core 3.1.
I am using the `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` extension method of a `DatabaseFacade` class.

C# code to get employee's count.

```
string deptName="IT";
int? employeeCount = null;
Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"exec dbo.usp_GetEmpCountByDept {deptName}, {employeeCount} out");
```

After execution employeeCount  is `null` and `-1` is the return value.
As some people requested stored proc code for reproducing the issue ,I have stored proc as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetEmpCountByDept
@Dept nvarchar(20),
@EmpCount int Output
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @EmpCount = COUNT(Id)
FROM [dbo].[Employees] 
WHERE Department = @Dept
END
```

Comment: and what is the code for the stored procedure?

Comment: Please also add a simple example for  a Store Procedure so we can reproduce.

Comment: That stored procedure *doesn't* return a value, it sets an output parameter. A stored procedure can have multiple output parameters. The `FromSql` methods will have to add an output parameter as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found other way which is working for me

1. Add Nuget package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
2. Use ExecuteSqlRaw method instead

Below is the code

```
    int? employeeCount = null;
    string deptName="IT";

    // Use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient namespace for SqlParameter.Visual studio will suggest  "system.data.sqlclient" which does not work
    var deptNameSQLParam = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Dept", deptName);
    var employeeCountSQLParam = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@EmpCount", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }; 
    Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec dbo.usp_GetEmpCountByDept @Dept={0}, @EmpCount={1} out", deptNameSQLParam, employeeCountSQLParam);

     if (employeeCountSQLParam.Value != DBNull.Value)
     {
        employeeCount = (int)employeeCountSQLParam.Value;
     }
```

Comment: How would you do this in EF Core 5?

Answer (score 5):

change this

```
string deptName="IT";
int? employeeCount = null;
Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"exec dbo.usp_GetEmpCountByDept {deptName}, {employeeCount} out");
```

to this (worked for me with .NET 5, don't know about earlier)

```
string deptName="IT";

// make explicit SQL Parameter
var output = new SqlParameter("@EmployeeCount", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

// use output parameter instead
Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"exec dbo.usp_GetEmpCountByDept {deptName}, {output} out");

// assign output
int? employeeCount = output.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteSqlInterpolated Executes the given SQL against the database and returns the number of rows affected.

You cannot expect data to be returned with this method.

Refer this MSDN documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlinterpolated?view=efcore-3.1