# Display declared variable from SQL Server stored procedure in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a stored procedure that returns 2 strings in the condition.

My problem now is if I use `ExecuteSqlRaw`, the return value is always -1.

This is my query for executing the stored procedure:

```
var delinquentSql = @$"
    DECLARE
      @return_value int, @Status nvarchar(50), @Code nvarchar(50), @UnitId nvarchar(50)
    EXEC
      @return_value = [dbo].[sp_CheckDelinquentStatus] @villageCode = N'{village.Name}',@block = N'{LopezProperties.BlockNumber}',@lot = N'{LopezProperties.LotNumber}',@Status = @Status OUTPUT,@Code = @Code OUTPUT,@UnitId = @UnitId OUTPUT
    SELECT
      @Status as N'@Status',@Code as N'@Code',@UnitId as N'@UnitId'
";
```

Is there any possibility that I can display the 2 strings (`@Status` and `@Code`) as returned values?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to execute stored procedure with Output parameters using FromSqlInterpolated/Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated in Dot Net Core 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59837665/8017690) `ExecuteSqlRaw` returns the number of rows affected, which normally used for insertion, update and delete. Thus I doubt it is suitable in your case.

Comment: I've just edited the code block to improve readability, please check if it looks right and also add the code that is invoking the sql string.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteSqlRaw returns the number of rows affected, and in document it is used for executing sql doesn't return any data, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#executing-non-querying-sql. So it is not feasible.

Use FromSql/FromSqlRaw, which is also recommended in the document.

```
//I use movie as sample here
var id = 1;
var Price = 7.99;
var IdParameter = new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = id };
var PriceParameter = new SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.Decimal) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = Price };
var result = _context.Movie.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.sp_CheckNum @param1,@param2",IdParameter,PriceParameter).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result[i].status);
    Console.WriteLine(result[i].code);
}
```

[image]

Note: In EF Core, you need to declare a dedicated type which is known as Keyless entity type to restore the strings you need, otherwise there may be some unexpected problems.

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public string UnitId { get; set; }
}
```

> define a DbSet

```
public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().HasNoKey();
}
```